# how to Dynamically obtain the universities from this array in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, html

How to Dynamically obtain the universities from this array in a JSON object, example:

```
let schools = {
  "School Canada": [{ 
    "Ontario": ["University of Toronto", "Ryeeson University"]
  }, { 
    "Alberta": ["University of Calgary", "University of Edmonton"]
  }],
  "School USA": [{ 
    "Texas": ["Towson University", "Texas Tech"]
  }, { 
    "Arizona": ["Penn Foster", "Pima College"]
  }]
}
```

When the button is clicked for either School Canada or School USA, I want the webpage to load like this:

School Canada

1. Ontario

   (a) University of Toronto

   (b) University of Ryerson
2. Alberta

   (a) University of Edmonton

   (b) University of Calgary

---

School USA

1. Texas

   (a) Towson University

   (b) Texas Tech
2. Arizona

   (a) Penn Foster

   (b) Pima College

---

And then the user can select whichever school he/she is from (radio buttons).

p.s: I've already created the buttons for school Canda and school USA dynamically.

Comment: What do you want to get as output? And fix your object.

Comment: Not very clear actually. If you show us the output you want to get that would be much more informative.

Comment: What do you mean by fix my object?.

Comment: Already fixed by me

Comment: I've added what the output is meant to look like

Comment: I'm afraid you asked wrong question. You don't need to retrieve universities form that object. You need to find out the way to use those data in your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It retrieves each university in an array:

```
let universities=[]
Object.keys(schools).forEach(schoolKey => {
 schools[schoolKey].forEach(state => {
  Object.keys(state).forEach(stateKey => {
   universities = [...universities, ...state[stateKey]] 
  })
 })
})
// universities =  ["University of Toronto", "Ryeeson University", "University of Calgary", "University of Edmonton", "Towson University", "Texas Tech", "Penn Foster", "Pima College"]
```